# Error message from MySQL

Tags: mysql

Here's my code. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong with it. The database is named inventory, the table is named data. I am trying to order from the earliest date in a field named check_up date, and pull the first two earliest. I want to exclude users that have the names "nobody", "mainconf" and "testing":

```
SELECT user
FROM data
ORDER by checkup_date
WHERE data.name != "nobody"
   AND WHERE data.name != "mainconf"
   AND WHERE data.name != "testing" ASC
LIMIT 2
```

Here's my error:

```
(1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
\'WHERE data.name != "nobody" AND WHERE data.name != "mainconf" AND WHERE
data.nam\' at line 1')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the errors:

1. The `ORDER BY` must be after the `WHERE` clausole and before the `LIMIT`
2. You don't need to repeat every time the `WHERE`. Just write the `AND` and you've done.

Comment: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'WHERE data.name != "mainconf" AND WHERE data.name != "testing" order by checkup_\' at line 1')

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Have you **really** read my answer? In the second point I assert that you have to have just **one** WHERE

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT user 
from data 
WHERE name != "nobody" AND name != "mainconf" AND name != "testing"
ORDER by checkup_date  ASC 
limit 2
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

**Order by** comes later (after **WHERE** and before **LIMIT**):

```
SELECT user from data WHERE data.name != "nobody" AND data.name != "mainconf" AND data.name != "testing" ORDER by checkup_date ASC limit 2
```

Comment: Right for the first part but WHERE must be not repetead!

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` clause needs to come before the `ORDER BY` clause. And you only need to specify the `WHERE` clause once.

```
SELECT user from data WHERE data.name != "nobody" AND data.name != "mainconf" AND data.name != "testing" ORDER by checkup_date ASC limit 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct MySQL syntax would be:

```
SELECT user from data  WHERE data.name != "nobody" AND data.name != "mainconf" AND data.name != "testing" ORDER by checkup_date ASC LIMIT 2
```

You don't need "WHERE" after each AND and the ORDER BY needs to be after all the WHERE-clauses.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
SELECT 
    user 
FROM 
    data  
WHERE 
    data.name != "nobody" AND data.name != "mainconf" AND data.name != "testing" 
ORDER BY 
    checkup_date ASC 
LIMIT 2
```